# Does Suse 9 support FAT32 file system?

Tags: linux, fat32

Does Suse 9 support FAT32 file system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All Linux distributions will mount FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

see man on "mount"

Comment: Man on mount? That would be Moses presumably :-)